# Es posible que un metodo retorne diferentes tipos de valores (int, String, etc)?

Tags: java

Tengo un metodo que se encarga de extraer y almacenar los datos de un cliente de un json:

```
private boolean obtenerDatosClienteDelJson(final JSONObject jsonObjectDatosCliente) {
    try {
        Bundle bundleDatosCliente = new Bundle();
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_ID, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_ID));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_NUMERO_CELULAR, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NUMERO_CELULAR));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL));
        return true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver, los datos del cliente estan siendo almacenados en un `Bundle`, lo que deseo es de que si todo se realiza correctamente que el metodo devuelva el `Bundle` y si algo sale mal que devuelva un valor booleano, quedando asi:

```
private boolean obtenerDatosClienteDelJson(final JSONObject jsonObjectDatosCliente) {
    try {
        Bundle bundleDatosCliente = new Bundle();
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_ID, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_ID));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_NUMERO_CELULAR, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NUMERO_CELULAR));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL));
        return bundleDatosCliente;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Es posible que un metodo retorne diferentes tipos de valores (int, String, etc)?

La respuesta sería un: **NO.**

> > Como pueden ver, los datos del cliente estan siendo almacenados en un Bundle, lo que deseo es de que si todo se realiza correctamente que el metodo devuelva el Bundle y si algo sale mal que devuelva un valor booleano

No necesariamente debes hacer que el método retorne dos valores de diferente tipo.

Una posible solución, es hacer que el método
`obtenerDatosClienteDelJson` sea de tipo `Bundle`.

Entonces para saber si el método se ejecutó con éxito, debe retornar un valor diferente de `null`.

Ejemplo:

```
//Si el método retorna null, es porqué hubo un error, de lo contrario, todo está bien.
private Bundle obtenerDatosClienteDelJson(final JSONObject jsonObjectDatosCliente) {
    try {
        Bundle bundleDatosCliente = new Bundle();
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_ID, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_ID));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_NUMERO_CELULAR, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NUMERO_CELULAR));
        bundleDatosCliente.putString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL, jsonObjectDatosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL));
        return bundleDatosCliente;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que se quiera conseguir, otra opción es eliminar el try-catch y simplemente dejar que se lance la excepción, delegando su captura al método que llama a `obtenerDatosClienteDelJson`.

Answer (score 0):

No se si mi respuesta sea la mejor ya que no entiendo tu código pero puedes hacer un método
que devuelva un Object así:

```
public class myClass {

    public myClass(){}

    public Object DevuelveObject(int i){
        switch(i){
            case 0: return false;
            case 1: return true;
            case 2: return String.valueOf(i);
            case 3: return i;
            case 4: return (float)i;
            case 5: return (double)i;
            default: return 'A';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass C = new myClass();
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(0));
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(1));
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(2));
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(3));
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(4));
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(5));
        System.out.println(C.DevuelveObject(6));
    }
}
```

el output es:

```
false
true
2
3
4.0
5.0
A
```

Comment: Si quieres procesar el valor devuelto, no es una buena idea que dicho valor pueda ser "cualquier cosa". Llenarías tu código con `if (... instanceof...)`

Answer (score 0):

Realmente, puedes pero no es un buena practica ya que, cuando escalas tu proyecto tienes que tener claro el tipo de datos que vas usar y mas cuando tienes una base de datos ya sea relacional o no, lo mejor es que analices exactamente, que tipo de datos vas a usar y por que y si te conviene ese tipo de dato en un futuro, recuerda que los tipo de datos primitivos, son mas óptimos por lo tanto tu app fluirá mejor